# Can't seem to get the addEventListener to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently stuck, as I can't seem to get the addEventListener to work.

I've tried the Dev. Tools with break points on addEventListener but they don't stop the script, so I guess there is something wrong with the code detecting the `click` and `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("links").style.display = "none";
};

function show() {
  document.getElementById("links").style.display = "flex";
};

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", show);
menu.addEventListener("mouseleave", hide);

menu.addEventListener("click", show);
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this != menu) {
    document.getElementById("links").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#menu {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}

#menu:hover {
  color: red;
}

#envelope {
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
}

#links {
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: pink;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#google {
  margin-top: -1vh;
  width: 150px;
}

#mysite {
  padding-left: 5%;
  margin-top: -1vh;
  width: 150px;
}

#menu:hover #links {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

#menu:focus #links {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

#menu:hover #envelope {
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu:focus #envelope {
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
  <div id="envelope">
    <div id="links">
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/si/"><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, Firefox Mac, but are you asking why the menu is closed, even if you click on the menu? Because if you click on a child element, that one will be "this". type `console.log(this);` in your click listener to see what I mean, or add "event" as an argument in your click listener and print it in the log.

Comment: Whether this is you requirement? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/zYGNQaP

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Yea, That is what I had in mind. Thank you. Post is as the anwser and I'll accept. =) Also please type what you changed.

Comment: Also, is there a way, that for an element to get `display: block` (or something) and that it transforms gradually (currently the element gets 100px height, although it should transform from 0 to 100)

Comment: @DrDoom, Added answer.. I couldn't find out ```100px``` height anywhere in your css.. Could you brief which element should be gets transformed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, a few modifications needed are,

In **css**, you are making `opacity: 0` for two elements `#envelope` and also `#links` which you could change the envelope to `opacity: 1` itself.

In **JS**, this line executes successfully,

```
document.getElementById("links").style.display = "flex";
```

But as already the css for `#links` is `opacity: 0`, it is not displaying so you need to make `opacity: 1` as well along with `display:flex` via JS..

So the code inside `show()` function, should be,

```
function show (){
    document.getElementById("links").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("links").style.opacity = "1";
};
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
function hide (){
 document.getElementById("links").style.display = "none";
};

function show (){
 document.getElementById("links").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("links").style.opacity = "1";
};

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", show);
menu.addEventListener("mouseleave", hide);

menu.addEventListener("click", show);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
  console.log(this != menu);
 if (this != menu){
  document.getElementById("links").style.display="none";
 }
});
```

```css
#menu{
 height: 10vh;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 1s ease-out;
 padding-top: 5vh;
}

#menu:hover{
 color: red;
}

#envelope{
 height: 0;
 display: block;
 background-color: blue;
 min-width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 content: "";
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
}

#links{
 height: 0;
 display: none; 
 background-color: pink; 
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#google{
 margin-top: -1vh;
 width: 150px;
}

#mysite{
 padding-left: 5%;
 margin-top: -1vh;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
  <div id="envelope">
   <div id="links" >
    <div><a href="https://www.google.com"><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a></div>
    <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/si/"><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png"/></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. =) And as requested earlier, the `#envelope`and `#links` both have `height:0` and on `:hover height:100px;`

Comment: @DrDoom, I have removed display properties and added ```visibility``` which only supports ```transition``` in a better way.. Here is the codepen with transition effects https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/RwPKzER

Comment: did you intentionally leave `document.getElementById("links").style.display="none";` inside the `if statement`?

Comment: @DrDoom, Yep sorry for that.. You can change it to ```visibility = "hidden"``` there as well..

Comment: could I also bother you to check this out... it's a continuation of this "project" and I'm getting wierd resoults... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396878/addeventlistener-adds-incorrect-properties-on-click-only-on-320x480

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, `addEventListener` is working, but it looks like the code is not producing the behavior you want or expect. You don't seem to be accounting for the way events propagate through the DOM.

You can read about that here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

You probably want something like the following:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked", event.target, this);
    if (event.target != menu) {
        /* something else was clicked */
    } else {
        /* the menu was clicked */
    }
});
```

Note that the click handler is naming an argument, called "event." Then we use `event.stopPropagation()` and look at `event.target` rather than `this`.

I've also added a `console.log` statement so you can see the difference between the `this` keyword and the value of `event.target`.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser. I'll check out the code to see what it does, as I'm not really that familiar with propegation and the diffrences between .this and event.