# addEventListener adds incorrect properties on click - only on 320x480

Tags: javascript, html

[image] **TL DR** it should be `display: flex; opacity: 1`

I have a menu which works in the following way:

- On mouseenter or click, the menu is shown (`display: flex`, `opacity: 1`)
- On mouseleave or click (outside the menu area) the menu is hidden (`display: none`, `opacity: 0`)

> **The problem occures** when I try to "open" the menu in the Dev. Tools **on 320x480** resolution.

When I `click` on the menu area, only `#envelope` does the transformation. `#links` (should also transform but don't becouse of the following reasons) which should get `display: flex` actually **gets `display: none` assigned to it.**

**Note: It's working in full screen. Something is bothering him with the 320x480 res.**

If I can elaborate or provide any additional information, let me know.

Thank you

```js
function hide (){
    document.getElementById("links").style.display = "none";
};

function show (){
    document.getElementById("links").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("links").style.opacity = "1";
};

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", show);
menu.addEventListener("mouseleave", hide);

menu.addEventListener("click", show);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
    if (this != menu){
        document.getElementById("links").style.display="none";
    }
});
```

```css
#menu{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    padding-top: 5vh;
}

#menu:hover{
    color: red;
}

#envelope{
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
}

#links{
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: pink;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}


#google{
    margin-top: -1vh;
    width: 150px;
}

#mysite{
    padding-left: 5%;
    margin-top: -1vh;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu:hover #envelope{
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu:focus #envelope{
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu:hover #links{
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
}

#menu:focus #links{
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
        <div id="envelope">
            <div id="links" >
                <div><a href="https://www.google.com"><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a></div>
                <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
                <div><a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/si/"><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png"/></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you testing toggling device mode? There is no hover in mobile device.

Comment: You know, you can solve this with pure CSS as well. :hover and :focus-within. No js code needed.

Comment: @Azametzin Yes, I've been trying it on toggle device mode. I know mobiles dont have hover (duh), but I didn't know toggle device takes that into account.

Comment: @RickardElimää I don't think I can solve it purely by css, as I can't get the effect I would like. The main problem was that the links were still clickable, because of the opacity. I wouldn't mind an example though.

Comment: Additinally, noone has addresed the real issue yet (`#links` get assigned the wrong value ie. `display: none;` )

Comment: Add `e` (the event object) to the argument list of the functions, and check `e.type` inside the function. You will find out, that not "wrong value" is assigned.

Comment: @Teemu how do I do that?

Comment: ?? console.log(e.type).

Comment: yea, it says click and mouseenter. But thats not what I'm talking about. I've also added a picture as I'm clearly not getting my meaning accross.

Comment: What's the purpose of #envelope, and animating that element when you have #links as a child that is much bigger? What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: I increased the `#links` size so I would see if it works... the style here is not relevant... the problem is incorrect arguments assigned to the `#links`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `transition: all` because the browser then need to loop through all properties, and it might cause lag.

Don't use `position: absolute` unless you have to.

I removed `#envelope` and inserted the "Click here ..." text in a label (explanation why below).

I arranged classes so I didn't have to repeat code.

---

Pure CSS solution below.

I made a little CSS hack, where I used a label and a checkbox to simulate a click. So when clicking on the `label#menu-toggler`, the (hidden) checkbox is checked, which triggers `#menu-toggler:checked ~ #links.invisible`. I had to add another class to `#links`, otherwise the low [specificity](http://v) wouldn't trigger the change.

```css
html, body { /* new */
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#menu {
  height: 15vh; /* changed */
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5rem; /* new */
}

#menu > input#menu-toggler { /* new */
  display: none;
}

#menu > .tagline { /* new */
  display: block; /* to get padding to work */
  padding: 5vh 0px;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#menu:hover > .tagline { /* new */
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu > .tagline,  /* new */
#menu > #links     /* new */
{
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#menu > #links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around; /* changed */

    position: relative; /* changed */
    left: -0.5rem; /* changed */
    top: -5vh; /* changed */
      
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;

    width: 100vw; /* changed */
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden; /* new */
    background-color: pink;
    
    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-duration: 1.3s;
}

#menu:hover #links,
#menu-toggler:checked ~ #links.invisible { /* new */
    height: 150px !important; /* changed */
    opacity: 1 !important; 
}

#links #google,
#links #mysite
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <input id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="menu-toggler" class="tagline">Click here to browse the internet.</label>
  
  <div id="links" class="invisible">
    <div><a href="https://www.google.com"><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/si/"><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png"/></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```